# How to call an API using node.js and include JSON string in the body?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express, request

I want to make http calls to an external API service.

However, the web server is expecting custom header and JSON string in the body.

I came across [request package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) and would like to use it.

Here is what I have done so far but not sure how to add json string to the request?

```
  var request = require('request')
  request({
    url: 'http://www.example.com/test',
    method: 'POST',

      headers: {
        {
          name: 'content-type',
          value: 'application/json'
        },
        {
          name: 'EXTERNAL-API-token',
          value: 'some string generated by the API'
        },
        {
          name: 'EXTERNAL-API-session-ID',
          value: 'some integer generated by the API'
        },
        {
          name: 'Cookie',
          value: 'some value received by the API'
        }
      }

  })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the 'json' and 'body' properties on the options object for the request:

```
var request = require('request')
request({
  url: 'http://www.example.com/test',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    {
      name: 'content-type',
      value: 'application/json'
    }, {
      name: 'EXTERNAL-API-token',
      value: 'some string generated by the API'
    }, {
      name: 'EXTERNAL-API-session-ID',
      value: 'some integer generated by the API'
    }, {
      name: 'Cookie',
      value: 'some value received by the API'
    }
  },
  json: true,
  body: {
    key: val
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Is there a better way to handle this? The syntax is too much here.

Comment: @MikeA Not that I know of. If you're re-using most of values for these properties, you could store them in a separate object, and then update the body as necessary.